# Django many to many with two models?

Tags: django

I have two models `Students, University`. By using this, student can apply for a course in university and the requirements is when a student apply for a course in university, i need to create a application ( planning to create separate model for application )

And this application can been accessed by both student & university. The purpose of making both access the application is because there are many post apply data's to be manipulated later !

So how to create a common application table - so both can access or its not effecient to create a seprate table ?

Please guide on how to tackle this !

```
Option1: Can a many to many be combined with Student and University to create a application model 

Option2: Add manytomany field to students model itself with University as foreign key ?
```

I have records about more than 1 million so am bit concerned about efficiency ! Which is better option to handle two way communication

Comment: Student hasMany Application belongsTo University…? Since a student is applying to a university, that would seem to be the logical relationship.

Comment: yes, students can have many application and also university also can have many students ! But how to create a relationship ? I thought of creating a extra table named Application

Comment: Yes. Application has a foreign key to both student and university, because an application is made by a student to a university. Separately from that, a student may have a many-to-many relationship to a university once they're actually enrolled.

Comment: surely you want a course model? so it would be student hasMany application belongsTo course belongsTo University as in:
Application has foreign key to course and student.
course has foreign key to uni.

Comment: yes, i already have course model assosiated with university ! what do you sugges ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this would be to have the intermediate model `Application` to contain foreign keys to both `Student` and `University`.

Having both foreign keys in the Application model would guarantee a many-to-many relationship between the Student and University.

The solution would be like so:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255)


class University(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Application(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(
        "Student",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    university = models.ForeignKey(
        "University",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option1: Can a many to many be combined with Student and University to create an application model
```

Option1 is answered by Ren.
For explanation, you may check [Django Features and Libraries
University of Michigan Video](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/django-features-libraries/a-simple-many-to-many-example-in-django-wPvNS)

Option2: This won't fulfill your requirements. Indeed Django will automatically generate a table to manage many-to-many relationships. You need to manually specify the intermediary table, you can use the through option to specify the Django model that represents the intermediate table that you want to use. i.e. Option 1

See [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) official doc.